# Is there any way to simplify this stream expression?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

```
protected static String paramsAsString(Object[] args) {
    return Arrays.stream(args).map((o) -> o != null && o.getClass().isArray() ? ArrayUtils.toString(o) : o)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).toString();
}
```

unit test

```
public void paramsAsString() throws Exception {
    String[] strings = {"1" , "2"};
    int[] ints = {3,4};
    int[] intsEmpty = {3,4};
    Object[] args = {"aaa" ,"zzz" , ints , strings, intsEmpty, null};
    String paramsAsString = paramsAsString(args);
    assertEquals("[aaa, zzz, {3,4}, {1,2}, {3,4}, null]", paramsAsString);
}
```

I'm just learning stream api. 
I wonder is there there any way to simplify this stream expression and remove the complex if?

Comment: I can't think of one except for pulling out the argument of `map` into a utility method, and use a handle to this method instead.

Comment: Do you know [`Arrays.deepToString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[]))? It does exactly what your code is about, well, it doesn’t switch between `[]` and `{}` braces…

Comment: One thing you can do is replace `.collect(Collectors.toList()).toString();` with `.collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));` to avoid the unnecessary intermediate `List` creation.

Answer (score 5):

If you just reference `ArrayUtils::toString`, you avoid the conditional:

```
protected static String paramsAsString(Object[] args) {
    return Arrays.stream(args)
                 .map(ArrayUtils::toString)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList()).toString();
}
```

but your test fails beause you get:

`[aaa, zzz, {3,4}, {1,2}, {3,4}, {}]`

instead of

`[aaa, zzz, {3,4}, {1,2}, {3,4}, null]`

You could "hack" this with a regex:

```
 return Arrays.stream(args)
              .map(ArrayUtils::toString)
              .collect(Collectors.toList())
              .toString().replaceAll("\\{\\}" , "null");
 }
```

---

But personally, i would keep the conditional and convert the lambda to another utility method:

```
public class MyArrayUtils {
     protected static String paramsAsString(Object[] args) {
         return Arrays.stream(args)
                      .map(MyArrayUtils::objectToString)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList()).toString();
     }

     private static String objectToString(Object object) {
         return object == null ? null : ArrayUtils.toString(object);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It’s not clear to me whether the output you expect is really what you want or if it is just an artifact of your current code (i.e. combining the output of the third-party library method `ArrayUtils.toString(o)` with `List.toString`).

When you simply use [`Arrays.deepToString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) you already get

```
"[aaa, zzz, [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], null]"
```

If you really want to use the `Stream` API as an exercise or want to have real control over the format, you may do it this way:

<sub>using `java.lang.reflect.Array`</sub>

```
public class MyArrayUtil {
    static String paramsAsString(Object o) {
        if(o==null) return "null";
        if(!o.getClass().isArray()) return o.toString();
        return IntStream.range(0, Array.getLength(o))
            .mapToObj(i->Array.get(o, i)).map(MyArrayUtil::paramsAsString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}"));
    }
}
```

This does not hide any utility method usage but is capable of formatting any array on its own. And it doesn’t create an intermediate `List` to use its `toString()` method. Instead, it uses the appropriate `Collector` which allows you to control the output. In the example above, I used `{`, `}` so the result will be:

```
{aaa, zzz, {3, 4}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, null}
```

If you want higher performance you may sacrifice readability and use the following derived code:

```
static String paramsAsString(Object o) {
    if(o==null) return "null";
    if(!o.getClass().isArray()) return o.toString();
    Stream<String> stream;
    if (o instanceof Object[]) {
        stream=Arrays.stream((Object[]) o).map(MyArrayUtil::paramsAsString);
    }
    else if (o instanceof int[]) {
        stream=Arrays.stream((int[])o).mapToObj(String::valueOf);
    }
    else if (o instanceof long[]) {
        stream=Arrays.stream((long[])o).mapToObj(String::valueOf);
    }
    else if (o instanceof double[]) {
        stream=Arrays.stream((double[])o).mapToObj(String::valueOf);
    }
    else stream=IntStream.range(0, Array.getLength(o))
        .mapToObj(i->Array.get(o, i)).map(Object::toString);
    return stream.collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}"));
}
```